# How to include image on left side and text on the right side for rmarkdown presentation

Tags: html, r, markdown, r-markdown, beamer

How can this be done in Markdown?

I am using the beamer presentation in Rmarkdown, and I want an image on the left side of a slide and text on the right side of a slide.

Basically, what this does: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165475/figure-next-to-text-in-beamer

But for Markdown not latex.

Comment: If someone proposes a solution that works when the output format is .pdf, it would make me a very happy man.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `multicol` package:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Martin"
date: "7/9/2017"
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{multicol}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdow

\begin{multicols}{2}

  \null \vfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{unnamed.png}
  \vfill \null

\columnbreak

  \null \vfill
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
  \end{itemize}
  \vfill \null
\end{multicols}
````

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to center the picture and text?  Mine appear at the top of the slide so there is black space at the bottom

Comment: Also is it possible to have the stuff on the right side be an itemized list?  I get an execution error when I try

Comment: Please scroll down people: [this is the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64285789/828193_

Answer (score 11):

You can do it in Pandoc's way! Refer to the [manual](https://www.pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#columns) for more information.

```
---
output: beamer_presentation
---

:::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="60%"}
![giraffe](giraffe.jpg)
:::
::: {.column width="40%"}
["Funny giraffe looking at the side"](https://www.flickr.com/photos/8070463@N03/9594476129) by [Tambako the Jaguar](https://www.flickr.com/photos/8070463@N03) is licensed under [CC BY-ND 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/?ref=ccsearch&atype=rich)
:::
::::
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I would not use the `multicol` package with beamer, beamer has its own mechanism for columns:

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "CambridgeUS"
    keep_tex: true

---

# test

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
  \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
    test
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

[image]

Comment: @ideus Using hard coded widths is really not a useful suggestion. The columns use relative widths and they will adjust if one changes the aspect ratio or similar. Combining this with hard coded lengths will destroy the layout.